# Return datas inside XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js

I have this function :

```
    function getDatas() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var response = null;
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "getdatas.php", true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
            if(xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                response = xmlhttp.responseText;
                return response;
            }
            else {return xmlhttp.statusText;}
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

The response is in a JSON format and correctly filled.
How to return the response for another use like :

```
var datas = getDatas();
```

UPDATE :
After the callback I have this :

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var _self = this;
    getDatas(function(error, result) {
        if(error) {
            alert(error);
        } else {
            _self.datas = result;
            console.log(_self.datas);
        }
    });
    console.log(_self.datas);
}
```

The first `console.log(_self.datas);` works well but the second is undefined.

Comment: and xhr request is async! however you could use es6 iterator to achive this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX is asynchronous, so you don't return any values from such functions, you use callbacks and use the value inside the callback:

```
function getDatas(callback) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var response = null;
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "getdatas.php", true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
            if(xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                response = xmlhttp.responseText;
                callback(null, response);
            }
            else {
               callback(xmlhttp.statusText, null);
            }
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

and then when you call the `getDatas` function you provide a callback which will be invoked when the AJAX request finishes and it will either contain the result or an error:

```
getDatas(function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
        alert('An error occurred while retrieving data: ' + error);
    } else {
        // Use the result variable here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help ! I updated my question, can you help me one more time ? :)

Comment: You can capture `this` just before calling the `getDatas` function: `var _self = this;` and then inside the callback use `_self.datas = result;`.